# To place text under each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, col

how to place text under each other?
Now i get this: [image]

But i want to get aligned text relative to each other

```
<Col span='8' style={{textJustify: 'inter-word'}}>
          <p style={{textAlign: 'justify'}}>Aug 20</p>
          <p style={{textAlign: 'justify '}}>Jul 20</p>
        </Col>
```

Comment: `p` has some default margin in its style.

Comment: have u tried giving margin to second `p`, if you want it to relative to first `p`

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap everything in 1 div then give that div a certain width and height

Answer (score 0):

to align items inline try this

```
<Col span='8' style={{textJustify: 'inter-word', display:"flex"}}>
  <p style={{textAlign: 'justify'}}>Aug 20</p>
  <p style={{textAlign: 'justify '}}>Jul 20</p>
</Col>
```

or

```
<Col span='8' style={{textJustify: 'inter-word'}}>
  <p style={{textAlign: 'justify', display:'inline'}}>Aug 20</p>
  <p style={{textAlign: 'justify ', display:'inline'}}>Jul 20</p>
</Col>
```